# Replacing a selected string in a selected column

Tags: python-2.7

I want to replace a particular (but common) string in some random lines of a a big file
As of now my code is to select random lines
I want to replace a common string belonging to the same column in the file in those randomly selected lines
An example input is:

```
ATOM      1  OH2 TIP3    1     -29.690   2.213   9.702  0.00  0.00      W1  
ATOM      2  OH2 TIP3    2       7.556 -17.910   8.218  0.00  0.00      W1  
ATOM      3  OH2 TIP3    3      33.654 -25.626  26.623  0.00  0.00      W1  
ATOM      4  OH2 TIP3    4      19.274 -19.602 -32.490  0.00  0.00      W1  
ATOM      5  OH2 TIP3    5      32.048   6.658  16.472  0.00  0.00      W1
```

The output for example is:

```
ATOM      1  OH2 TIP3    1     -29.690   2.213   9.702  0.00  0.00      W1  
ATOM      2   UT TIP3    2       7.556 -17.910   8.218  0.00  0.00      W1  
ATOM      3  OH2 TIP3    3      33.654 -25.626  26.623  0.00  0.00      W1  
ATOM      4  OH2 TIP3    4      19.274 -19.602 -32.490  0.00  0.00      W1  
ATOM      5   UT TIP3    5      32.048   6.658  16.472  0.00  0.00      W1
```

I want to change the string OH2 to UT for randomly selected lines
P.S.: Spacing is important in output
This is my code right now.

```
file=sys.argv[1]  
ncsolv=string.atoi(sys.argv[2])     # no. of random lines to select
finp = map(string.split, open(file,'r').readlines())  
atname=map( lambda line: line[2], finp)  
ndata=len(atname)      
nwat=ndata/3    
new_list=[]  
#print ncsolv,nwat  
while (len(new_list)<2):  
      k=int(random.uniform(0,nwat))  
      flag=0  
#      print k  
      for j in new_list:  
          if (j==k):  
             flag=1  
             exit  
      if (flag==0):   new_list.append(k)
```

Comment: Can you show us your code and where you're stuck with? or a file sample in input / expected output. Too broad without that.

Comment: @Jean-FrançoisFabre any ideas please

Comment: I'd like to help, but you have to improve your question again: sample inputs & outputs as _text_ please. I don't want to retype them :)

Comment: @Jean-FrançoisFabre done